# **[UPDATE]** How to animating background expandation of cardview in android?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-cardview

I'm developing a weather app. In my UI, I have animation like this one below. I want when a use click on CardView, it and it's background expand as much as remaining height of the phone's screen with animation. It's background change with animation like the .gif below :

Please help me to implement that. Thanks :)

[image]

I searched too much for implement it but I didn't find anything that help me.

**[UPDATE]**

I need something like trasition animation between activiries. I dont know if there is someway like that inside one activity or not.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `layoutChangeAnimation` property of parent layout to `true` and then use this dependency:

[ExpectAnim](https://github.com/florent37/ExpectAnim)